# Hashtable with linked lists, duplicate nodes still saving (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable, nodes

sorry if I make any mistakes in the way I should be presenting this but my problem is after I create the new node for the linked list and then it's first duplicate node(judged by the username) creates a new node but all the rest of the duplicates work fine. [image]

NEW NAME get's called when a new node is to be created (Hashtable node is NULL) then after the next entry gets created it doesn't see that there is a original value which i thought 'if(temp->userName == tempUser)' would fix. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
void linkedList::addNode(Node ** table, int hashLocation, string tempUser, string tempStart, string tempCPU, string tempPath, int tempPID)
{
    Node * temp = table[hashLocation];
    bool isTaken = false;

    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << "TEMP'S USERNAME = " << temp->userName << endl;
        while (temp->next != NULL && isTaken == false) //&& tempUser != temp->userName)
        {
            cout << "USERNAME = " << temp->next->userName  << "TEMPUSER = " << tempUser << endl;
            if(temp->userName == tempUser) // PROBLEM HERE NOT BEING SET TO TAKEN
            {
                isTaken = true;
            }
            if(isTaken == false)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        cout << "Exited loop" << endl;
        cout << "IS TAKEN = " << isTaken << endl;
        if(isTaken == true)
        {
            cout << "ITS TAKEN" << endl;
            string tempMinute, tempSecond;

            temp->processID.push_back(tempPID);

            istringstream iss(tempCPU);


            getline(iss, tempMinute, ':');
            getline(iss, tempSecond);

            temp->minuteCount.push_back(atoi(tempMinute.c_str()));
            temp->secondCount.push_back(atoi(tempSecond.c_str()));

            temp->pathName.push_back(tempPath);
            temp->timeStart.push_back(tempStart);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NOT TAKEN" << endl;
            temp->next = new Node(tempUser, tempStart, tempCPU, tempPath, tempPID);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NEW NAME: " << tempUser << endl;
        table[hashLocation] = new Node(tempUser, tempStart, tempCPU, tempPath, tempPID);
        //cout << "TEMP'S USERNAME = " << temp->userName << endl;
    }
}

class Node
{
    public:
        Node();
        ~Node();
        Node(string tempUser, string tempStart, string tempCPU, string tempPath, int tempPID);
        Node * next;

        vector<int> processID, minuteCount, secondCount;
        vector<string> pathName, timeStart;
        string userName;

    private:


};
```

And this is the call from main

```
aList.addNode(aHash.getTable(), aHash.hashValue(tempUser), tempUser, tempStart, tempCPU, tempPath, tempPID);
```

I've checked the values it's receiving and they are all correct.

Comment: Unrelated: Every time an *image* of code or terminal output is posted in a question, a kitten dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the last element in the list, because you are checking `temp->next` is not equal to NULL and the last element has no next element.

Put your test for temp->next inside the loop:

```
    while (isTaken == false) //&& tempUser != temp->userName)
    {
        cout << "USERNAME = " << temp->userName  << "TEMPUSER = " << tempUser << endl;
        if(temp->userName == tempUser) // PROBLEM HERE NOT BEING SET TO TAKEN
        {
            isTaken = true;
        }
        if(temp->next == NULL)
            break;
        if(isTaken == false)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
```

Also, output temp->userName to cout, not temp->next->userName

Comment: Thank you very much including the additional help after comment, great job!